# Add a color scheme for Fortran source files

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, fortran, color-scheme

I just managed to get gfortran to compile properly, with Xcode Tools 4.2 installed on Mac OS 7 Lion. But now whenever I edit a .f90 file in Vim (terminal) there is no color scheme.

How can I add a color scheme to Vim for editing Fortran files?

Comment: If OP tags this 'vim' it may attract more people more knowledgable about vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have this line in your .vimrc:

```
syntax on
```

If that doesn't fix it, also add this (although this should get picked up automatically) to your .vimrc:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.f90 set filetype=fortran
```

Comment: haha, I actually saw this under the fortran tag but couldn't check for sure until I got home from work :)